# Converting Groovy tasks build.gradle to kotlin kts file

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to convert my build.gradle file in Groovy to a kotlin .kts file, I have some tasks in the gradle file that I dont know how to convert correctly

```
task androidJavadocs(type: Javadoc) {
    failOnError = false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext.androidJar = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar"
    classpath += files(ext.androidJar)
    exclude '**/R.html', '**/R.*.html', '**/index.html'
}

task androidJavadocsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: androidJavadocs) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from androidJavadocs.destinationDir
}
```

I dont quite understand how to use the "type", I was going down this path

```
val androidJavadocs by tasks.withType<Javadoc>(){

}
```

but its giving me the error

> Type 'DomainObjectCollection<Javadoc!>' has no method
> 'getValue(Build_gradle, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a
> delegate

How do I convert those groovy tasks to kotlin tasks correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `named()` method to configure existing tasks and the `register()` method to create new ones.

```
tasks {
    register<Javadoc>("androidJavadocs") {
        // Task's body here
    }
}

// or

tasks.register<Javadoc>("androidJavadocs") {
    // Task's body here
}
```

If you want to use Kotlin delegated properties

```
val androidJavadocs by tasks.registering(Javadoc::class) {
    // Task's body here
}
```

The full answer to your question

```
val androidJavadocs by tasks.registering(Javadoc::class) {
    isFailOnError = false
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    ext["androidJar"] = "${android.sdkDirectory}/platforms/${android.compileSdkVersion}/android.jar")
    classpath += files(ext["androidJar"])
    exclude("**/R.html", "**/R.*.html", "**/index.html")
}

val androidJavadocsJar by tasks.registering(Jar::class) {
    classifier = "javadoc"
    dependsOn(androidJavadocs)
    from(androidJavadocs.get().destinationDir)
}
```

Comment: With that the issue that I am having now is that `main` is not resolved in `android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs` but that might be more of an android question